# How can I display a log scale colorbar with Matlab R2015a?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, surface, colorbar

I am trying to display a 3D plot with the function surf in Matlab and I need it to be in log scale for the z-axis. So here is what I am doing :

```
surf(X,Y,Z)
set(gca,'zscale','log')
```

But I would like the colorbar to appear in log scale, with labels like 10^(-6), 10^(-5), 10^(-4),...

Looking it up, I found out about the solution

```
h = colorbar
set(h,'YScale','log')
```

but it's not working with the newest versions of Matlab because the `'YScale'` parameter doesn't exist anymore.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you can change the colorbar axis and labels to a log scale, your data is still not in log scale, and so the colorbar will appear strange. To fix this I can suggest another dummy axes to hold the colorbar. Here is how:

Let's say you plot this:

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(50);
s = surf(X,Y,Z);
set(gca,'zscale','log')
h = colorbar;
```

Our next step is to get the axes position after the colorbar insertion (for future use):

```
axpos = s.Parent.Position;
```

Now we create new axes, hide them, and add a colorbar in the same position of the first one:

```
axes;
axis off
cb = colorbar('Position',h.Position);
```

Next we adjust the colobar axis to values that are displayed in the plot (since `Z<=0` are not displayed):

```
caxis(log10([min(Z(Z>0)) max(Z(:))]))
```

we change the colorbar ticks labels to the log-scale format:

```
cb.TickLabels = sprintf('10^{%1.1f}\n',cb.Ticks);
```

Finally, we delete the first colorbar, and set the axes position back to `axpos`:

```
delete(h)
set(s.Parent,'Position',axpos)
```

and we get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get the idea but still, while running the exact same code as you I get an error for the line "axpos = s.Parent.Position". Matlab is telling me "Attempt to reference field of non-structure array". Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: @MarieC You right. I had a little typo there it should be `s = surf(X,Y,Z);`. now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question in the [MATLAB forum](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/203697-logarithmic-scale-for-colorbar).

The gist: you can get the `caxis` and modify it for `log` values:

```
caxis(log([c(1) c(length(c))]));
colorbar('FontSize',11,'YTick',log(c),'YTickLabel',c);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get what would be the vector c in my case... I am just plotting a function of two variables

Comment: c is your vector of data, as the colorbar limits are derived from there.